# How to change WinMerge font size?

Tags: fonts, winmerge

How can I change WinMerge font size and perhaps the font type?

Is it possible?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Click on View-> Select Font !

[image]

Comment: Windows "clear case" to smooth fonts doesn't seem to work :-/

Comment: When you change the font like this you _might_ get a message that the active window will not be updated. Resolution: open it again. (Why I mention this is that if you just press Ok on the message you will not receive it again and a day later you will have forgotten it. And google. And find this comment.)

Comment: Every time I set up WinMerge I need to search for this setting. I wonder why the font settings are not part of the WinMerge options found under "Edit" -> "Options".

Comment: ...and again :(((((((((

Comment: Note that a document must be opened for the *Select Font* option to show up. That little quirk just cost me some time to find out...

Answer (score 8):

Did you try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Mouse Wheel</kbd>?

Comment: That works. But if you restart, the setting is gone.

Comment: Yes, indeed the setting is lost, maybe we can tweek it on Windows registry?

Comment: Maybe you could use @Junior Mayhé solution and mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: He can't cause it doesn't work